# Using elephas on jupyter test notebooks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, keras

I don't have a spark cluster at hand, but I want to fiddle around with [elephas](https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas), so I'm using temporary instances at [try.jupyter.org](http://try.jupyter.org).

You'll find at the bottom of this question all of my code (for reproducibility), and the full error log, but here is a short description of my problem :

When I run my code, I end up getting three types of error. The first one is :

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'constraints'
> ```

The second one :

> ```
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException
> ```

And I also see this third error :

> ```
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
> ```

I don't really get which of these three errors is the one crashing my code, each one seems to indicate a different origin. Therefore, I'm wondering if I get these errors :

- because of an error/incompatibility between some of the libraries involved (between `keras` and `elephas`, for instance), as the first error seems to imply ;
- because of a mistake in my code (if so, what is it ?), as the second error seems to imply (see the first answer [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/65743/pyspark-failuer-sparksparkexception-job-aborted-du.html)) ;
- or because what I'm trying to do is not possible (technically prohibited) with the `try.jupyter.org` instances (if so, I'm curious why), as the third error seems to imply.

---

My code :

```
# First, go to try.jupyter.org
# If it says "No Vacancy", wait a bit and refresh
# If not, then select "Welcome to Spark with Python.ipynb"
# Clean all the cells

import pip
pip.main(["install", "--upgrade", "git+https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas"])
# I sometimes get error 128. If so, shutdown the kernel, open a new try.jupiter.org window, and try again from line 1.
# Do NOT do "pip install elephas", it installs an older build of elephas which is not compatible with keras 1+

pip.main(["install", "--upgrade", "tensorflow"])
import keras
import hyperas, flask, elephas

# start a SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Elephas_App').setMaster('local[8]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc

# keras model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model = Sequential()

from keras.layers import Dense
model.add(Dense(units = 100 # number of neurons in the first layer
                , activation = 'sigmoid' 
                , input_dim = 30 
                , bias_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean = 0.1, stddev = 0.05) 
                ))
model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid')) 

# see the neural network
model.summary()

# load dataset
from sklearn import datasets
cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
cancer.data

# dataset into pd.dataframe
import pandas as pd
donnee = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data = cancer.data, columns = cancer.feature_names), 
                   pd.DataFrame(data = cancer.target, columns = ["target"])
                      ], axis = 1)

# train/test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(donnee.loc[:, donnee.columns != "target"], donnee.target, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 1)

from elephas.utils.rdd_utils import to_simple_rdd
rdd = to_simple_rdd(sc, X_train, y_train)

from elephas.spark_model import SparkModel
from elephas import optimizers as elephas_optimizers

adagrad = elephas_optimizers.Adagrad()
spark_model = SparkModel(sc, model, optimizer=adagrad, frequency='epoch', mode='asynchronous', num_workers=2)
spark_model.train(rdd, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_split=0.1)
```

---

The full log generated by the last 3 lines of my code, including error log :

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
172.17.0.55 - - [05/Jan/2018 10:41:26] "GET /parameters HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.55 - - [05/Jan/2018 10:41:26] "POST /update HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py", line 160, in update_parameters
    constraints = self.master_network.model.constraints
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'constraints'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-44a540be31e8> in <module>()
----> 1 spark_model.train(rdd, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_split=0.1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py in train(self, rdd, nb_epoch, batch_size, verbose, validation_split)
    195 
    196         if self.mode in ['asynchronous', 'synchronous', 'hogwild']:
--> 197             self._train(rdd, nb_epoch, batch_size, verbose, validation_split, master_url)
    198         else:
    199             print("""Choose from one of the modes: asynchronous, synchronous or hogwild""")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py in _train(self, rdd, nb_epoch, batch_size, verbose, validation_split, master_url)
    215                 self.master_optimizer, self.master_loss, self.master_metrics, self.custom_objects
    216             )
--> 217             rdd.mapPartitions(worker.train).collect()
    218             new_parameters = get_server_weights(master_url)
    219         elif self.mode == 'synchronous':

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py", line 311, in train
    put_deltas_to_server(deltas, self.master_url)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py", line 44, in put_deltas_to_server
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py", line 311, in train
    put_deltas_to_server(deltas, self.master_url)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elephas/spark_model.py", line 44, in put_deltas_to_server
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```